# Swift - Return data from NSURLSession when sending POST request

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, post, nsurlconnection

I can send a POST request in Swift using the below code

```
func post() -> String{
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://myserverip/myfile.php")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "data=xxxxxxx"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in
        if error != nil {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        println("response = \(response)")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("responseString = \(responseString!)")

    }
    task.resume()



    return "";//how would i return data here
}
```

I need to return the result, but this isn't possible since the network request is asynchronous. I think I can use a listener to wait for the result and then return it, but I'm not sure how this would work or how to implement it
If anyone could help, I would greatly appreciate it
I am new to both iOS and Swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your post function might be like:

```
func post(completionHandler: (response: String) -> ()) { your code }
```

And in the response part:

```
let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
completionHandler(response: responseString)
```

Finally, you can call your post method like:

```
post( {(response: String) -> () in
               println("response = \(response)")})
```

Comment: Thank you. I just got this same solution from somewhere else but thank you anyway. Ill accept your answer since its the solution i used. For reference, this is where i got it https://thatthinginswift.com/completion-handlers/

Answer (score 2):

You can use a delegate or pass a function as an argument of post that you call at the end

Example with a completion handler :

```
 struct RemoteCenter {
    static func post(completion: (message: String?) -> Void) {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://myserverip/myfile.php")!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        let postString = "data=xxxxxxx"
        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                println("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            completion(message: NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String)
        }

        task.resume()
    }
}

class YourController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        RemoteCenter.post(completionHandler)
    }

    func completionHandler(message: String?){
        println("I got \(message)")
    }
}
```

Example with a delegate :

```
protocol DelegateProtocol {
    func didReceiveAMessage(message: String?)
}

struct RemoteCenter {
    var delegate:DelegateProtocol?

    func post() {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://myserverip/myfile.php")!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        let postString = "data=xxxxxxx"
        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                println("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            self.delegate?.didReceiveAMessage(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String)
        }

        task.resume()
    }
}

class YourController: UIViewController, DelegateProtocol {

    var remote = RemoteCenter()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        remote.delegate = self
        remote.post()
    }

    func didReceiveAMessage(message: String?) {
        println("I got \(message)")
    }
}
```

In both cases, the goal is to fetch some data on the internet from an UIViewController and print the message when it's done.

You can find so many tutorials about it. Check http://www.raywenderlich.com

Comment: Could you give an example? Like i said, Im new to this